# removing case senstivity from a string

Tags: android

i perform a special action if the string equals something. However, i want to perform the same action if the string has uppercase characters. but i dont want to write so many else if statements for every case-

decrypt

Decrypt

DECRYPT

```
 } else if (message.equals("decrypt")) {
                        removeencryption(context);
```

is there a way of removing case sensitivity?

i have already tried

```
} else if (message.toLowerCase().equals("whistle")) {
                    whistle(context);
```

but it is not working

Comment: Also, for this case, I would consider using enums

Answer (score 0):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase` method of `String` class:

```
else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt")) {
                        removeencryption(context);
}
```